# What's the purpose of the body in/after resurrection?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, olam-haba-world-to-come, resurrection-of-the-dead

Following "[what-is-the-purpose-of-tchiat-hametim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14639/what-is-the-purpose-of-tchiat-hametim-ressurection-of-the-dead)", the Gemmorah says:

> העולם הבא אין בו לא אכילה ולא שתיה ולא פריה ורביה ולא משא ומתן ולא קנאה ולא שנאה ולא תחרות אלא צדיקים יושבין ועטרותיהם בראשיהם ונהנים מזיו השכינה שנאמר ויחזו את האלהים ויאכלו וישתו
>
> The World-to-Come (WTC) is not like this world: there is no eating, no drinking, no procreation, no business negotiations, no jealousy, no hatred, and no competition. Rather, the righteous sit with their crowns upon their heads, enjoying the splendor of the Divine Presence ([Brochos 17a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.17a.12?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi))

IIRC there are two (contradicting) [approaches](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90#%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99) to that time - whether the Gemmorah speaks of the WTC *before* the resurrection or it speaks *about* after the resurrection (RASA"G).

In either case, what's the need for physical bodies if there's no physical activities, no Mitzvos only spiritual pleasure?

Comment: Isn't the quoted Talmud passage speaking about the afterlife (where the souls go to after they leave the body)?

Comment: Scholars have been asking that question for centuries. Some feel that the Rambam felt that the resurrection is only spiritual for why would the soul want to rejoin the body if they are in bliss. Others feel that the Rambam wrote about a physical resurrection. In either case the Rambam says not to focus on resurrection for the soul enjoys a state of bliss more so then resurrection. This has led some to speculate that the Rambam himself did not believe in a physical resurrection but wrote about it because of necessary beliefs. If this is not the case, one is still clueless for its purpose.